# Java Catch block exception class in a variable

Tags: java, performance

I have a requirement where I am writing a retry logic and in that I need to `catch exception` depending on function which will be passed in argument so is it possible in `java` to determine if the caught exception matches the `exception` passed in argument ?

basically:

```
retryfunc(func,Exception... retryableexceptions,int retries){

    try {
        func.apply();
    }catch(...){}//How to validate if exception is of retryable type ?
}
```

Comment: Wait, what?  You're passing in an array of exceptions and you want to somehow match an element in the array to see if it's one of the exceptions you need to do some extra work on, or want to retry?  What differentiates these exceptions from any other system exception?  Is there a `RetryableException` class that these inherit from?

Comment: I wonder why Exception array has been comes into play when all forces us to focus on concrete type of exceptions one by one? Perhaps you have a multi-catch block. I think it would be better, if you mention how this method is being called from outside.

Comment: You mean you're going to pre-create some exception objects, call this method, and you want it to catch only exceptions that have already been supplied? Or of the class(es) that have already been supplied? Doesn't make much sense. Anyway not implementable in Java, unless you roll it all yourself via `instanceof`. Which is not the idea at all. You need to rethink all this.

Comment: try `Class.isInstance(e)`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are passing a list of exceptions which are "Retry-able Exceptions" and you want to know whether the exception, generated by that method call, is one of them.

If that is the case then you can do following:

```
retryfunc(func, Exception... retryableExceptionList, int retries){

    try {
        func.apply();
    }catch(Exception e){

        for (Exception retryableException : retryableExceptionList) {
              if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(retryableException.getClass())) {
                   System.out.println("We need to retry buddy..");
                   break;
                }
          }
    }
}
```